# Depoloying ABP Framework MAUI Application to Android 11 device throws error

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, abp-framework

I was trying to deploy my **ABP Framework MAUI** application to **Android 11 (API Level 30)** device via **Visual Studio 2022**, and came across with the following error:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
  Message=An exception was thrown while activating MyProject.Maui.App -> MyProject.Maui.AppShell.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Execute>b__0()
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateSharedInstance(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateSharedInstance(Guid primaryId, Nullable`1 qualifyingId, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ScopeSelectionMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\MauiContext.cs:line 68
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\MauiContext.cs:line 68
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[IApplication](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiApplication.OnCreate() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiApplication.cs:line 37
   at Android.App.Application.n_OnCreate(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Android.App.Application.cs:line 1072
   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 22
```

I've searched for this error and stumbled on similar errors but there was different reasons at the core of the issues so different solutions were applied, none of which did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this issue:

- First I ensured that my MAUI **AndroidManifest** satisfies both the
  `Minimum Android version` and the `Target Android version` of the device I was trying to deploy.
- Then I checked if I had the required Android SDKs installed, with
  going to `Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager`. On the Platform
  tab, I noticed that even though I had **Android SDK Platform 30** installed, I haven't got the `Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image` installed.

After the installation, I was able to deploy and debug my application on the Android 11 Zebra device.

Here's the final look of my Android SDKs and Tools window:
[image: Android SDKs and Tools image]